# How to download data from a password protected website

Tags: python

I'm using request in python to try and download this file: 
http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL1.003/2000.02.11/N55W003.SRTMGL1.hgt.zip there are 14000 such files hence why I need to automate the process. The other techniques I've found online don't seem to work. I assume due the websites they are designed for using a different authentication method. I don't know much about web development so I can't work out how this authentication works.

Edit

This is the code:

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


file = open("srtm30m_bounding_boxes.json", 'r')
strjson = file.read()
x = json.loads(strjson)

filenamelist = []

url = "http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL1.003/2000.02.11/N55W003.SRTMGL1.hgt.zip"

for i in range(14295):
    filenamelist.append(x['features'][i]['properties']['dataFile'])
    filenamelist[i] = "http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL1.003/2000.02.11/" + filenamelist[i]

jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
jar.set('urs_user_already_logged', 'yes')
jar.set('_urs-gui_session','8b972449036e60e3d83a6a819b93124d')
r = requests.get(url, cookies=jar)
```

And this is the error I get when I run the code:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: Please provide the code you already tried

Comment: Also provide what exactly `didn't work`

Comment: Thanks, I've added that

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to provide the username and password in the URL before the host, e.g.:

```
requests.get('http://{username}:{password}@e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL1.003/2000.02.11/{subpath}'.format(username=username, password=password, subpath=filenamelist[i]))
```

You can also supply the username/password as the `auth` parameter to get:

```
requests.get('http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL1.003/2000.02.11/{subpath}'.format(subpath=filenamelist[i]), auth=(username, password))
```

totalhack is right that https is more secure, and it seems to work on this site.  This form of authentication transmits the username and password as plaintext, so anyone who can observe the http request would also be able to steal your login.  https encrypts the username / password since it encrypts the entire request.

Comment: One should really be using HTTPS with basic auth. I realize you are just copying what the OP has for URLs.

Comment: Thank you very much, did you test this? It doesn't seem to work (I still get a 401 error with both of these methods)

Comment: I tested it with a different site that uses HTTP Basic auth, and then changed the URL when I posted the code.  If it doesn't work but you're able to use that username / password interactively, I don't know why.  You could try putting the username:password@host form into your browser.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it uses HTTP Basic auth the URL that you are redirected to has the words OAuth in it. Which is my only evidence for the previous statement.

Comment: When I click your zip file, I get a password prompt.  When I cancel the password prompt, it says "HTTP Basic: Access denied.".  The HTTP headers on that page include "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Please enter your Earthdata Login credentials. If you do not have a Earthdata Login, create one at https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov//users/new""

So whatever else it's doing, it's doing HTTP Basic.

Comment: Okay, It doesn't seem to work however I think I may have found a different source for the data I can use without the password stuff. Thank you so much for your help anyway.